# Tensorflow Keras Models Load_Model Can't hidden Model object With Python

Tags: python

I want to hide my model.

```
class A()
    __model = tf.keras.models.load_model(my_model_path)

a = A().__dict__
```

It shows _A__model func

when user do

```
a._A__model.to_json()
```

they can get my model.

how can I hide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private

> “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object **don’t exist** in Python.

According to it, you can't hide any attribute.

But you can use `__getattribute__()` to restrict access to your model.

[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**getattribute**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)

Comment: Thanks, I thihk I gonna to override func to_json.